# How to set oracle_home in linux with ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, oracle-home

Am trying to set `oracle_home` by using below

```
---
- name: setting up the ORACLE_HOME
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  environment:
    ORACLE_BASE: "/u01/app/oracle/"
    ORACLE_HOME: $ORACLE_BASE/product/12.1.0.2/cl_100
    PATH: $PATH:$HOME/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch
```

script executing but not setting up please help

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the following:

```
  vars:
    ORACLE_BASE: "/u01/app/oracle"
    ORACLE_HOME: "{{ORACLE_BASE}}/product/12.1.0.2/cl_100"
    ADD_PATH: "{{ORACLE_HOME}}/bin:{{ORACLE_HOME}}/OPatch"
  environment:
    ORACLE_BASE: "{{ORACLE_BASE}}"
    ORACLE_HOME: "{{ORACLE_HOME}}"
    PATH: "{{ansible_env.PATH}}:{{ansible_env.HOME}}/bin:{{ADD_PATH}}"
```